# Reading bytes from the serial port

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

Im building an application where i need to reed 15 byes from a serial device. (ScaleXtric c7042 powerbase) The bytes need to come in the right order, and the last one is a crc.

Using this code in an backgroundworker, I get the bytes:

```
byte[] data = new byte[_APB.ReadBufferSize];
_APB.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```

The problem is that I don't get the first bytes first, Its like it stores some of the bytes in the buffer, so next time the DataRecieved event fires, I get the last x bytes from the previous message, and only the 15-x byte from the new. I write the bytes to a text box, and its all over the place, so some bytes are missing somewhere.

I have tried to clear the buffer after each read, but no luck.

```
_APB = new SerialPort(comboBoxCommAPB.SelectedItem.ToString());
_APB.BaudRate = 19200;
_APB.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandlerDataFromAPB);
_APB.Open();
_APB.DiscardInBuffer();
```

Hope any one can help me here

Comment: You only get the bytes currently available in the receive buffer, usually only 1 or 2.  Counting them off so you get them all is up to you.  [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18899964/17034).

Answer (score 1):

Use this Method to read fixed amout of bytes from serial port, for your case `toread = 15;`

```
 public byte[] ReadFromSerialPort(SerialPort serialPort, int toRead)
 {
     byte[] buffer = new byte[toRead];
     int offset = 0;
     int read;

    while (toRead > 0 && (read = serialPort.Read(buffer, offset, toRead)) > 0)
    {
        offset += read;
        toRead -= read;
    }
    if (toRead > 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();

    return buffer;
}
```